# Guardar multiple images en Laravel con Intervention Image

Tags: laravel, imagen, intervention

Necesito guardar multiples imagenes, pero solo logro guardar 1

Este es mi input

```
 <input type="file" name="images" id="images" multiple>
```

Este es mi controller, estoy almacenando mis imagenes en mi base de datos

```
       $image_file = $request->images;
  
       $image = Image::make($image_file);
  
       Response::make($image->encode('jpeg'));

       $form_data = array(
        'images' => $image
       );
  
       Obras::create($form_data);
  
       return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Image store in database successfully');
```

**Selecciono multiple imagenes y solo se guarda la primera, pero necesito guardar varias al mismo tiempo**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

parece ser que tu problema reside en el `name` del `input` que usas para guardar las imágenes.

Yo lo crearía de la siguiente manera:

```html
 <input type="file" name="images[]" id="images" multiple>
```

Y en el controlador, lo haría de esta manera:

```js
 $images = $request->images; // Tendrá TODAS las imágenes
  
 foreach($images as $image){
 
   //No hay necesidad de usar Response con Image Intervention a menos que trates las imágenes pero es válido
   $new_image = Image::make($image);

   $image->encode('jpeg'); 
  
  /*
   $form_data = array(
    'images' => $image //Aquí no sé por qué se llama images, pero si es una sola imagen se guardaría la ruta de solo una imagen. Si son varias imágenes, podrías almacenar un JSON con todas las rutas. Si es solo una debería de llamarse image. Yo borraría esta parte
   );
   */

   Obras::create(["image" => $image]); //Asegúrate de tener un mutador en tu modelo Obras
 }

 return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Images stored successfully');
```

Y sería todo :)

Comment: Muchas GRACIASS

Comment: De nada, siéntete en libertad de publicar todas tus dudas: Bienvenido a StackOverflow :)